# how to overflow text to do this

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple elements each has a `short` and `main` divs. I want to keep `short` to one line. Right now, when the content exceeds one line, it moves to the next line. What I want however is to make it cut off the remaining text and display dots like this `...` instead. Is this possible?

```
<div class="elem">
  <div class="short">   Text should stay on one line   </div>
  <div class="main">  </div>
</div>

.elem{
  width:150px;
}
```

Ideally, when the user hovers over the title and dots `...`, he could see the full title in a simple html pop-up or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS will achieve the effect you want in browsers with CSS3 support:

```
.elem { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 150px; }
.elem:hover { white-space: normal; }
```

Note that the text will expand when the mouse is over any part of it, not just the ellipsis.

Comment: for some reason, `text-overflow` isn't being picked up. Is this an official css attribute?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Check this table to see if it supports text-overflow: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: My mistake. I missed `overflow: hidden;` from the .elem style. I've updated the answer. This article explains how to emulate `text-overflow` in Firefox: http://www.jide.fr/english/emulate-text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-with-css

Answer (score 2):

For a Jquery solution, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kA3uN/

```
$short = $('.short');
$short.html($short.html().substring(0,10) + " ...");
```

Just change `10` to whatever character length agrees with your layout.  No need for CSS3! :D

Comment: I like this solution but the number of characters is probably not what I'm after. For example `llllllllll` has different width than `ZZZZZZZZZZ`

Comment: @zmol - If you're using web safe fonts, the letter width won't be drastically different... but maybe just leave a bit of padding on the end. Relying on CSS3 isn't smart--not sure what else to suggest :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS's 3 `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property

EDIT

Sorry, guess I clicked to fast on send and didn't read the full question. With that CSS property you can clip the text to the width you want.

If you want it to appear on hover you only have to increase the div's width with the hover pseudo class like:

```
.elem:hover {
  width: 300px:
}
```

Comment: for some reason, `text-overflow` isn't being picked up. Is this an official css attribute?